# need an advice with orientation change iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

my problem might be simple to some of you but i can't find a solution. I have a method where a create my views automatically (text fields, labels and text views). It's like a registration form. The problem is that when i change the screen to landscape mode, i want to change the views width. To do that i used `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` and created the views again. The problem is that the views won't get recreated with the landscape width. I can't use IB to autosize the views at orientation change. The views are created in `viewDidLoad` and removed and recreated in `- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {}` I don't know why they don't get recreated after being removed. If there was another solution that you could share with me i would appreciate it.

**Here's how i create the views:**

```
-(void)createViews:(int)width
{
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTextfields; i++) {
        textfieldPadding = textfieldPadding+40;//set some space between the text fields
        labelPadding = labelPadding+40;//set some space between the labels

        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(10,i*textfieldHeight+textfieldPadding+firstTextfieldHeight+10,width, textfieldHeight)]; 
        field.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        //field.backgroundColor= [UIColor cyanColor];
        field.placeholder = [labels objectAtIndex:i];
        field.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        field.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        [field addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:)

        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, i*labelHeight+firstLabelHeight+labelPadding-20, width, labelHeight)];

        label.text = [labels objectAtIndex:i];
        //label.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:field];
        [scrollView addSubview:label];

        [textfields addObject:field];
        [labels addObject:label];
        [field release];
        [label release];
    }
}
```

**Here's where i wanted to remove them and recreate them:**

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation 
{    
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self createViews:landscapeWidth];
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self createViews:portraitWidth];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you dont need to recreate view right ? instead you can change frame accordingly when orientation changes....

Comment: can you post code?so that we can see what you are doing

Comment: check out the edits. I put some code.

Comment: you can add a method in your code where you will change frame of all subviews by getting their tag and changing..let -(void)createViews:(int)width called only once..you dont need recreate everytime. change only frame depending upon orientation .add a method newly to change orientatin alone .

Comment: Between your existing code and Narayanan's suggestions you'd be writing an awful lot of code you really don't need. Just let the `autoresizingMask` do it's job, it's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing, resizing and then re-adding as you currently are why not just set the appropriate `autoresizingMask` ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6)) when you create the view initially?

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];
// the following will automatically resize the width on orientation change
myTextField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; 
[myView addSubview:myTextField];
[myTextField release];
```

Comment: It won't work because you are not allowing the masks to do their job as you are removing the views. **Seriously, you don't need to remove any views**. Delete the method `adjustViewsForOrientation` and then you should see the desired effect.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked because in the `adjustViewsForOrientation` i only removed the `removeFromSuperview` method but i was still creating the views again. I removed the two methods and it's working. Thanks a lot!